# function unable to work with user inputs?

Tags: python

I have the following code, which is a code for a connect 4 game, the problem is that the functions seem to break in the user input part of the code. I don't know if I accidentally edited something to break it but I'm almost certain that it isn't as typing the adding this to the code:

```
addcounter(1,1)
addcounter(1,1)
addcounter(1,1)
addcounter(1,1)
addcounter(2,1)
addcounter(2,1)
addcounter(2,1)
addcounter(3,1)
addcounter(3,1)
addcounter(4,1)
checkdiagonal(4,1,1)
```

The output of this does return true as expected.

The code is as follows:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sun Dec 22 17:24:35 2019

@author: Norbert
"""

import numpy as np

h = 8
w = 9
x = 0
y = 0
playspace = np.zeros((h,w))
playspace[:, [0,-1]] = 8




def addcounter(column,team):
    placed = False
    while not placed:
        for i in range(h-1,0,-1):
            if playspace[i,column] > 0:
                continue
            else:
                if team == 1:
                    playspace[i,column] = 1
                if team == 2:
                    playspace[i,column] = 2
                if team != 1 and team != 2:
                    print("error, invalid team")
                placed = True
                break

def height(column):
    for i in range(h-1,0,-1):
        if playspace[i,column] > 0:
            continue
        else:
            return i

def checkhorizontal(y,x,team):
    a1 = 0
    a2 = 0
    a3 = 0
    a4 = 0
    for i in range(4):
        try:
            if playspace[h-y,x+i] == team:
                a1 += 1
            if playspace[h-y,x+i-1] == team:
                a2 += 1
            if playspace[h-y,x+i-2] ==team:
                a3 += 1
            if playspace[h-y,x+i-3] ==team:
                a4 += 1
        except:
            pass
    if (a1 == 4) or (a2 == 4) or (a3 == 4) or (a4 == 4):
        return True

def checkvertical(y,x,team):
    a1 = 0
    a2 = 0
    a3 = 0
    a4 = 0
    checking = playspace[:,x]
    for i in range(4):
        try:
            if checking[h-(y+i)] == team:
                a1 += 1
            if checking[h-(y+i-1)] == team:
                a2 += 1
            if checking[h-(y+i-2)] ==team:
                a3 += 1
            if checking[h-(y+i-3)] == team:
                a4 += 1
        except:
            pass
    if (a1 == 4) or (a2 == 4) or (a3 == 4) or (a4 == 4):
        return True


def checkdiagonal(y,x,team):
    diag1 = 0
    diag2 = 0
    if playspace[h-y,x] == team:
            diag1 += 1
            diag2 += 1
    for i in range(1,4):
        broken1 = False
        try:
            if playspace[h-y+i,x+i] == team and not broken1:
                diag1 += 1
            if playspace[h-y+i,x+i] != team:
                broken1 = True
        except:
            pass

    for i in range(1,4):
        broken2 = False
        try:
            if playspace[h-y-i,x-i] == team and not broken2:
                diag1 += 1
            if playspace[h-y-i,x-i] != team:
                broken2 = True
        except:
            pass

    for i in range(1,4):
        broken3 = False
        try:
            if playspace[h-y+i,x-i] == team and not broken3:
                diag2 += 1
            if playspace[h-y+i,x-i] != team:
                broken3 = True
        except:
            pass

    for i in range(1,4):
        broken4 = False
        try:
            if playspace[h-y-i,x+i] == team and not broken4:
                diag2 += 1
            if playspace[h-y-i,x+i] != team:
                broken4 = False
        except:
            pass

    if (diag1 >= 4) or (diag2 >= 4):
        return True

finished = False
turn = 0
team_turn = 1
print(playspace)
while not finished:
    valid = False
    print("turn: {}".format(turn))
    print("It is player {}'s turn".format(team_turn))
    while not valid:
        player_input = int(input("Where would you like to drop a counter?"))
        if playspace[0,player_input] != 0:
            print("That isn't a valid column")
        else:
            valid = True
    if team_turn == 1:
        addcounter(player_input,team_turn)
        if checkhorizontal(height(player_input),player_input,team_turn) == True or checkvertical(height(player_input),player_input,team_turn) == True or checkdiagonal(height(player_input),player_input,team_turn) == True:
            print("Player {} wins".format(team_turn))
            finished = True
    if team_turn == 2:
       addcounter(player_input,team_turn)
       if checkhorizontal(height(player_input),player_input,team_turn) == True or checkvertical(height(player_input),player_input,team_turn) == True or checkdiagonal(height(player_input),player_input,team_turn) == True:
            print("Player {} wins".format(team_turn))
            finished = True
    turn += 1
    turn_changed = False
    while not turn_changed:
        if team_turn == 1:
            team_turn = 2
            turn_changed = True
            break
        if team_turn == 2:
            team_turn = 1
            turn_changed = True
            break
    print(playspace)
```

any help in trying to solve the bugs in the code would be grately appreciated. The connect 4 game uses simple 2-d arrays to display and store the game board. I have plans to use this array to create a pygame later on.

EDIT:
To clarify, the checks don't run to execute a victory message and end the game. despite the if statements being True. Only the vertical win seems to end the game.

Comment: Please cut this down to a [mcve].

Comment: The only user input part is `player_input = int(input("Where would you like to dro a counter?"))` What problem is it having?

Comment: I recommend the following article: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to correct the horizontal part, the code correction is as follows:

```
if (checkhorizontal(height(player_input)+1,player_input,team_turn) == True) or (checkvertical(height(player_input),player_input,team_turn) == True) or (checkdiagonal(height(player_input),player_input,team_turn) == True):
```

and in the horizontalcheck function:

```
def checkhorizontal(y,x,team):
    a1 = 0
    a2 = 0
    a3 = 0
    a4 = 0
    checking = playspace[y,:]
    print(checking)
    for i in range(4):
        try:
            if checking[x+i] == team:
                a1 += 1
            if checking[x+i-1] == team:
                a2 += 1
            if checking[x+i-2] ==team:
                a3 += 1
            if checking[x+i-3] ==team:
                a4 += 1
        except:
            pass
        print(a1,a2,a3,a4)
    if (a1 == 4) or (a2 == 4) or (a3 == 4) or (a4 == 4):
        return True
```

Ignore the prints, they're for debugging. But I basically removed one dimension and flipped the h-y value to become the y value.